# Error parsing JSON, POST containing \r\n at the begining of JSON

Tags: java, api, grails, groovy, jackson

I have created an API to create notes in my app with a contract and its client. The client is basically a Factory to manage Api instances and a helper to inject configurations and some interceptors for metrics and Basic Auth.

I created an easy and small java application to test the client.

Everything looks find, the client creates the instance correctly and use the api objects to create the request (it is a POST) and sent it. The server receives the request and process authentication correctly but then it throws this error:

> org.grails.web.json.JSONException: Unterminated string at character
>   311 of \r\n{"noteUser":"user.user","subject":"Flight ticket issued
>   onlydescription this booking has the flight issued only, please check
>   if any ancillery needs to be booked","description":"GONZALO TEST:
>   ok?this booking has the flight issued only , please check if any
>   ancillery needs to be booked","bookingId":"433301392

Debuging I have found these:

It seems like non **\r\n** is added in client - log:

```
2018-09-04 09:48:52 DEBUG RestDefaultHttpClient:643 - Attempt 1 to execute request
2018-09-04 09:48:52 DEBUG DefaultClientConnection:264 - Sending request: POST /uno/v3/notes/addNote HTTP/1.1
2018-09-04 09:48:52 DEBUG wire:63 - >> "POST /uno/v3/notes/addNote HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
2018-09-04 09:48:52 DEBUG wire:63 - >> "Accept: application/json;charset="UTF-8"[\r][\n]"
2018-09-04 09:48:52 DEBUG wire:63 - >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate[\r][\n]"
2018-09-04 09:48:52 DEBUG wire:63 - >> "Content-Length: 311[\r][\n]"
2018-09-04 09:48:52 DEBUG wire:63 - >> "Content-Type: application/json;charset="UTF-8"[\r][\n]"
2018-09-04 09:48:52 DEBUG wire:63 - >> "Host: localhost:8080[\r][\n]"
2018-09-04 09:48:52 DEBUG wire:63 - >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
2018-09-04 09:48:52 DEBUG wire:63 - >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.2 (java 1.5)[\r][\n]"
2018-09-04 09:48:52 DEBUG wire:63 - >> "Authorization: Basic bW9yZ2FuLmZyZWVtYW46UGFuY2V0YTE=[\r][\n]"
2018-09-04 09:48:52 DEBUG wire:63 - >> "[\r][\n]"
2018-09-04 09:48:52 DEBUG wire:63 - >> "[\r][\n]"
2018-09-04 09:48:52 DEBUG headers:268 - >> POST /uno/v3/notes/addNote HTTP/1.1
2018-09-04 09:48:52 DEBUG headers:271 - >> Accept: application/json;charset="UTF-8"
2018-09-04 09:48:52 DEBUG headers:271 - >> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
2018-09-04 09:48:52 DEBUG headers:271 - >> Content-Length: 311
2018-09-04 09:48:52 DEBUG headers:271 - >> Content-Type: application/json;charset="UTF-8"
2018-09-04 09:48:52 DEBUG headers:271 - >> Host: localhost:8080
2018-09-04 09:48:52 DEBUG headers:271 - >> Connection: Keep-Alive
2018-09-04 09:48:52 DEBUG headers:271 - >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.2 (java 1.5)
2018-09-04 09:48:52 DEBUG headers:271 - >> Authorization: Basic bW9yZ2FuLmZyZWVrtetUGFuY2V0YTE=

2018-09-04 09:48:52 DEBUG wire:77 - >> "{"noteUser":"user.user","subject":"Flight ticket issued onlydescription this booking has the flight issued only, please check if any ancillery needs to be booked","description":"GON TEST: ok?this booking has the flight issued only , please check if any ancillery needs to be booked","bookingId":"113301392"}"
2018-09-04 09:49:53 DEBUG DefaultClientConnection:165 - Connection closed
```

And these is the request.JSON in the server:

```
\r\n{"noteUser":"user.user","subject":"Flight ticket issued onlydescription this booking has the flight issued only, please check if any ancillery needs to be booked","description":"GONZALO TEST: ok?this booking has the flight issued only , please check if any ancillery needs to be booked","bookingId":"113301392
```

[image]

As you can see in the server, the request has a \r\n at the begining of the JSON and it is missing "} at the end of it. I thing this is because the Content-Length is set to 311 and due to somehow 2 characters are added at the begining of the JSON (\r\n), 2 char are missing at the end.

I have debug until the request is sent to the server an I cannot find the \r\n added:

[image]
[image]

- I am using grails 3.3.2 and linux in the server (with linux line separator LF)
- Client is done in java 1.8 and windows (with windows line separator CRLF)
- jackson it is used to handle JSON.
- Basic Auth is manage by spring.

I have squeezed my brain and I have run out of ideas. Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I do the request with an external application like postman, it works. So it looks a client issue but I have no idea where.

Comment: Where's your client code?

Comment: I can provide it but I was not sure if it will be useful and I use some enterprise code that I am not sure if I can show it, but I will ask tomorrow and post as much as they allow me. Thanks

Comment: It looks like whatever client you are using is adding crlf to the request body